# Coverting codes into procedures in x86 MASM

Tags: assembly, procedure, masm

I have a program in x86 MASM assembly language that is able sort an array. However, I want to turn this into a procedure so that I'm able to use it for multiple arrays. Can you help me with converting these codes into a procedure? And also,in the procedure, can you show me how to print the sorted array onto the black screen (this is a feature that I wanted but wasn't able to implement due to my lack of knowledge in assembly language).

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

    .data
    arrayD       dword          5,9,10,2,3
    .code
    main PROC
        mov ebx, 5
    OuterLoop: ; sorting the array in descending order
        mov esi, offset arrayD
    
        mov ecx, ebx       
    InnerLoop:
        Lodsd
        mov edx, [esi]
        cmp eax, edx
        jl Skip
        mov [esi], eax
        mov [esi-4], edx 
    
    Skip:
        dec ecx
        jnz InnerLoop
        dec ebx
        jnz OuterLoop
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the procedure as a callable piece of code (*blackbox*) with documented input, output and functionality. Decide how should your procedure accept input parameters (*calling convention*), create its documentation and then write the code, supplemented with instruction RET (which makes it callable). Be sure to keep the stack balanced, if instructions PUSH and POP are used in the code.

```
BubbleSort: ; Procedure to sort an array of double-words.
; Input:  EDI is pointer to the unsorted array of DWORDs.
;         EBX is number of DWORDs in the input array.
; Output: The array is sorted in descending order.
;         EAX,EBX,ECX,EDX,ESI are clobbered.
 OuterLoop: ; sorting the array in descending order
        mov esi,edi
        mov ecx, ebx       
    InnerLoop:
        Lodsd
        mov edx, [esi]
        cmp eax, edx
        jl Skip
        mov [esi], eax  ; Swap neighbouring DWORDs.
        mov [esi-4], edx 
    Skip:
        dec ecx
        jnz InnerLoop
        dec ebx
        jnz OuterLoop
        RET
```

Exemplary invokation of your procedure:

```
mov edi, offset arrayD 
mov ebx,5
CALL BubleSort
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but do you know how can I print the contents of the array onto the screen inside this procedure? P/s edit: Nevermind, I've figured it out, thank you for you input!